# In F#, how to sort on a Nullable property?

Tags: f#

I have an array downloaded from a database where the property service_time is `Nullable<DateTime>`:

```
service_time: Nullable<DateTime>
```

In F#, how can I sort this array, placing all the elements with service_time = null firstmost in the new array?

```
Array.sortBy (fun t -> t.service_time)
```

gives: *The type 'Nullable' does not support the 'comparison' constraint.*

Comment: Have you tried `Array.sortBy`? Any specific problems with it?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Yes. The type 'Nullable<DateTime>' does not support the 'comparison' constraint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that `default(DateTime)` equals [`DateTime.MinValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.minvalue?view=net-5.0) and sort on [`service_time.GetValueOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.getvalueordefault?view=net-5.0) like so:

```
Array.sortBy (fun t -> t.service_time.GetValueOrDefault())
```

Or, more explicitly:

```
Array.sortBy (fun t -> t.service_time.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MinValue))
```

If you wanted to put the nulls at the end of the array you could do:

```
Array.sortBy (fun t -> t.service_time.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MaxValue))
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pRyZGc).